# Views: Single Image Per Tag

Tags: nodes, views, media

For examples purposes. Say I created a content type called ContentX with a image field and term reference field(Tag). I created 4 node(pages) of ContentX. All 4 nodes of ContentX have 1 Image to each node. Two of these nodes of ContentX have a Tag called TagA.  Two of these nodes of ContentX have a Tag called TagB.

I then create a view block stating that I want to view content from ContentX. In the view fields I make sure the images field is there. All 4 images of ContentX show.

THE ISSUE:
Say I want to show a single image from the 2 nodes with TagA. I go to filters,Content:TagA, check One Of: and bring up my tag which is TagA. HOWEVER instead of showing what I believe to be "One Of TagA", it shows both images of both nodes with TagA Tag.

THE OUTCOME I AM TRYING TO GET: 
I am trying to get my View to show one image from 2 ContentX nodes with a Tag called TagA and one image from 2 ContentX  nodes with a Tag called TagB.

Any help?

Comment: The question is: which image for TagA nodes should views display? Image from node1 or from node2? You are not telling that to views anywhere. If image for TagA is the same across all nodes, you may want to add an image field to a taxonomy (or any other entity referenced by your reference field), then add relationships to your view and show the proper field.

Answer (score 0):

In views **pagerer** you can limit "**Items to display** " section and give the option as 1 to limit ome image to display from that filter